# From vectorial to cartesian form of a line

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a doubt in this problem!
What's the cartesian form of the parametric line $$r:(x,y,z)=(1,2,0)+\alpha(1,1,1)$$
I tried substitution, as I usually do, but this time I have some doubt...
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Cartesian form of a line in 3D is two equations that all points on the line satisfy.

At the moment you have:
$$
\begin{align}
x&= 1+\alpha\\
y&= 2+\alpha\\
z&=\alpha
\end{align}
$$
Substituting the third equation into the other two gives 
$$
\begin{align}
x&= 1+z\\
y&= 2+z
\end{align}
$$
This is a possible Cartesian form.

In most maths courses, they expect three expressions connected by = signs. The simplest way to do that is to rearrange all to be equal to $\alpha$:
\begin{align}
x-1&=\alpha\\
y-2&=\alpha\\
z&=\alpha
\end{align}
Now set them all equal, since they're all equal to $\alpha$:
$$
x-1=y-2=z
$$